# Get gene names corresponding to CPG probes

Tags: r, illumina

I have downloaded KIRC Methylation data (450K) using TCGA toolbox. The beta values given are with reference to CPG probes. Is there any package or function in R through which I can get the gene names corresponding to these probes? I was able to get the gene I.Ds using `getMappedEntrezIDs`. Is there any function to map these I.Ds to respective gene names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a Python script (e.g., called `map_entrez_to_ensembl.py` that uses [mygene.info](https://github.com/biothings/mygene.py) to convert a list of Entrez IDs to Ensembl gene names:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import mygene

mg = mygene.MyGeneInfo()

genes = ['3815',
         '3816',
         '2341']

results = mg.querymany(genes, scopes=['entrezgene'], fields=['ensembl'], species='human', verbose=False)

for res in results:
    entrez_id = res['query']
    if 'ensembl' in res and 'gene' in res['ensembl']:
        sys.stdout.write('%s\t%s\n' % (entrez_id, res['ensembl']['gene']))
```

Result:

```
$ ./map_entrez_to_ensembl.py 
3815    ENSG00000157404
3816    ENSG00000167748
```

Looks like there's an [R-based interface to mygene.info](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/mygene.html), if you really need to use R.

You could use their [API test page](http://mygene.info/tryapi/) to see how data are structured and what keywords are available for different kinds of searches.

For instance, if you wanted aliases, in addition to Ensembl names:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import mygene

mg = mygene.MyGeneInfo()

genes = ['3815',
         '3816',
         '2341']

results = mg.querymany(genes, scopes=['entrezgene'], fields=['ensembl', 'alias'], species='human', verbose=False)

for res in results:
    entrez_id = res['query']
    if 'ensembl' in res and 'gene' in res['ensembl'] and 'alias' in res:
        for alias in res['alias']:
            sys.stdout.write('%s\t%s\t%s\n' % (entrez_id, alias, res['ensembl']['gene']))
```

Then:

```
$ ./map_entrez_to_alias_and_ensembl.py
3815    C-Kit   ENSG00000157404
3815    CD117   ENSG00000157404
3815    PBT     ENSG00000157404
3815    SCFR    ENSG00000157404
3816    KLKR    ENSG00000167748
3816    Klk6    ENSG00000167748
3816    hK1     ENSG00000167748
```